# Does my ISP control me behind NAT

Tags: networking, router, proxy, nat, isp

I called customer service several times I said I want to open ports myself as I want and I said take me out off froum your firewall.They said they fixed it but I'm sure they don't and they just put off me. They probably control me behind NAT.  Furthermore, i think it causes more ping around 25-30 ms than before.

My ping was previously around 17 but now it always higher than 48.(lol,csgo, speed test etc.)

[image: imgur.com/zfKTcHC]

tracert (8.8.8.8)

[image: imgur.com/gcoXrF9]

tracert superuser.com

[image: imgur.com/bcMYKSM]

why does every single connection pass through 31.155.48.85 IP address that belongs to my ISP ? (at third hop.)

whoer.net says that my ISP maybe uses proxy

[image: imgur.com/c3JqxWQ]

is that an ISP proxy ? if yes, is there any law enforcement?

Comment: It passes through IP addresses owned by your ISP because, by definition, _all_ your traffic passes through your ISP's network. How could it possibly work otherwise?

Comment: All information in the right columns is more or less pure speculation.

Comment: Previously, my internet were connecting directly to POP after second hop. However, now there is one more connection which belongs to my ISP. therefore, I didn't have any kind of ping problem before. Now  I have.
few months ago my tracert results 
[link](http://imgur.com/1ly8rqs)

Comment: Yeah, so your ISP changed its internal network hierarchy. That’s normal and there’s nothing you can do about it. You can file a complaint, of course, but legally everything’s fine.

Answer (score 0):

It would be extreme overkill (and return false information) if an ISP was proxying ping requests.

You have no control of how the ISP routes traffic beyond your router or modem.  This idea of being controlled behind NAT is a little silly, because NAT implies that your device doesn't have a real public IP address (whether static or dynamic), but a NATted one.

In the end, this comes down to how you are *testing* these ports that are purportedly opened or closed.  If your testing approach is incorrect, or you aren't configuring your port forwarding correctly on your router (are you doing this at all?), then of course it will look like something's gone bad at the ISP level.